# ES6 and webpack: Redux: How to import a file from a distant directory

Tags: reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, webpack, redux

I'm working on a project with React and Redux, and a lot of my Redux actions/reducers are re-usable, so they reside in a common folder outside of the current project.

I'm trying to include the Redux actions and reducers, but I get the following webpack error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/PreApp.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '..../../../../../themes/fuelled-base/lib/fuelled-core/register/fuelled-redux-base/base-actions' in /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/fuelledv2/wp-content/plugins/fuelled-lunch-menus/admin/js/scripts/src/components
 @ ./src/components/PreApp.js 15:19-124
```

I've also tried including said file(s) in webpack itself, but get this error:

```
ERROR in /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/fuelledv2/wp-content/themes/fuelled-base/lib/fuelled-core/register/fuelled-redux-base/base-reducers.js
Module parse failed: /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/fuelledv2/wp-content/themes/fuelled-base/lib/fuelled-core/register/fuelled-redux-base/base-reducers.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
| import {
|   REQUEST_FUELLED_WP_API_ENTITIES,
```

Is there a correct way to include these files?

My webpack.config.js file looks like this when trying to include the file via webpack:

```
'use strict';

let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/components/Root.js',__dirname + '../../../../../../themes/fuelled-base/lib/fuelled-core/register/fuelled-redux-base/base-reducers.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../'),
        filename: 'fuelled-lunch-menus-admin.js',
        devtoolLineToLine: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /src\/.+.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And like this when trying to include the file via the JS file in which I want to use it instead of webpack:

```
'use strict';

let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/components/Root.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../'),
        filename: 'fuelled-lunch-menus-admin.js',
        devtoolLineToLine: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /src\/.+.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If what I'm asking isn't totally clear, the "TL;DR" version of my question is:

I have two directories (the first of which contains reducers and actions I want) :

```
(1) /wp-content/themes/fuelled-base/lib/fuelled-core/register/fuelled-redux-base/base-reducers.js

(2) /wp-content/plugins/fuelled-lunch-menus/admin/js/scripts/src/components/configureStore.js
```

In (2) I have this import:

```
import rootReducer from '../../../../../../../themes/fuelled-base/lib/fuelled-core/register/base-reducers'
```

And it doesn't work. And I've tried importing the file via Webpack instead, and that also doesn't work.

Any suggestions / pointers would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: bundle your reusable components as a private module and `npm link yourprivatemodule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your test regex for the babel loader includes the `src` directory, which your `themes` path doesn't contain. Because the babel `test` regex is not matched, webpack can't find an appropriate loader and throws the error.

You could try to extend the regex to include the `fuelled-base` directory for example (or if possible, just leave out the `src\/` part in the first place):

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/components/Root.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../'),
        filename: 'fuelled-lunch-menus-admin.js',
        devtoolLineToLine: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(src|fuelled-base)\/.+.jsx?$/, // or simply: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Bonus: Nicer paths**

If you want to avoid such awful relative paths, you can configure the [`resolve` option in webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) to include the following paths:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    root: [ // in case you are using webpack 2, this is called "modules" now
        path.resolve(yourProjectPath, 'node_modules'), // you probably want to keep this
        path.resolve(yourWordpressPath, 'wp-content') // here you use wp-content as a base path
    ]
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
import rootReducer from 'themes/fuelled-base/lib/fuelled-core/register/base-reducers'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

I get this error though:

`ReferenceError: yourProjectPath is not defined`

When I replace your 2 vars with paths, I get:

`ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/fuelledv2/wp-content/plugins/fuelled-lunch-menus/admin/js/scripts/node_modules/src/components/Root.js in /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/fuelledv2/wp-content/plugins/fuelled-lunch-menus/admin/js/scripts`

(even though the directory + file in the error are correct).

Comment: (I'm guessing yourProjectPath and yourWordpressPath were variables? If so, the original issue is still there (in a sense) because I have to replace those two things with paths?

So for 'yourProjectPath' I could use:  `__dirname + '/node_modules'`

But then the issue is that `yourWordpressPath` is much further up the directory tree (about 5 directories above), so I still have to reference that with `../../../../../` ?

Comment: yes, if you have your webpack config deeply nested as well, you will need to use a relative path in your `resolve.root` for `wp-content` as well.

Comment: Using `path.resolve` will clean up the relative paths nicely though, and you will only need to specify it in your webpack config, not your application files. And yes, `yourProjectPath` and `yourWordpressPath` are dummy variables for your actual paths. Let me know if it doesn't work out.